# How to control a closed kinematic chain in Gazebo?

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, ros-foxy, ros2-control, gazebo-ros2-control

I am trying to control a closed kinematic chain in Gazebo 11 using [ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/foxy/index.html) and [gazebo_ros2_control](https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/tree/0.1.1). I know, that closed kinematic chains are not supported by URDF, therefore I've closed the loop via [SDF injection](https://answers.ros.org/question/404825/easiest-way-for-closed-kinematic-chain/). The models get loaded properly, so I wanted to control them using:

*complete_robot.urdf.xacro*

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
    <parameters>$(arg ur_simulation_controllers)</parameters>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

*onrobot_ros2_control.urdf.xacro*

```
...
<ros2_control name="${gripper_name} type="system">
  <hardware>
    <xacro:if value="${sim_gazebo}">
      <plugin>gazebo_ros2_control/GazeboSystem</plugin>
    </xacro:if>
    ...
  </hardware>
  <!-- Joints -->
  ...
</ros2_control>
...
```

I tried to use a JointTrajectoryController for the control of the closed loop, but even before I send messages to the controller topic my gazebo server reports repeating warnings inside its log (.gazebo/server-11345/default.log):

```
[Wrn][Joint.cc:821] failed to find a clean set of connected links, i.e. this joint is inside a loop, cannot SetPosition kinematically.
[Dbg][Link.cc] we have a loop! cannot find nice subset of connected links, this link RG6_left_inner_knuckle connects back to parent wrist_3_link.
```

I think I'm not the only person using closed kinematic chains, since they are somewhat common in robotics (delta robots, grippers, etc). I also have found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5O9mDumzZUw) where someone is controlling such a kinematic loop, but in ROS1 according to the linked [repository](https://github.com/AytacKahveci/gazebo_closed_loop_hw_sim/tree/master). Could someone point me in the right direction on how to achieve the controlled closed loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I also use it.
First recommendation: Update to a ROS distribution which is not EOL already.

Which interface are you using? (position, velocity,...) How many joints do you want to control? You only can control a single joint of the closed-loop kinematics, the position of the others will be solved by gazebo.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to come back to the question. I'm updating to Humble. For the closed-loop, I want to control the position of one of the joints (it is a OnRobot Gripper).
What is your approach Christoph?

Comment: Model your kinematic chain as described [here](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=kinematic_loop&cat=), add a single command interface according to your hardware (where your real actuator is located), and add optionally state interfaces to all joints of the kinematic loop if you wish.

Comment: Then use the single command interface in any ros2_controller (position_controller, joint_trajectory_controller, gripper_controller, ...)